# Converting [IO String] to IO String in evaluation of parsed expression

Tags: parsing, haskell

In the language I'm writing at the moment, I'm trying to implement a function which evaluates the entire program based on what I have written already as I can only execute one statement at a time. The function allows me to parse and evaluate files from a file.

The function `evalString` is the problem. The function executes perfectly if it's last line were `runIOThrows $ liftM show $ evalStatement env (x!!0)` for example. I felt like the natural step to take was to use `map` but that just gives me `[IO String]` rather than `IO String`.

If I make the return of the function `[IO String]` however there exists an error with the `readStatement` function and evalAndPrint function:

```
----- readStatement -----
Couldn't match type ‘IO’ with ‘[]’
      Expected type: [[HStatement]]
        Actual type: IO [HStatement]

----- evalAndPrint -----
Couldn't match type ‘[]’ with ‘IO’
      Expected type: IO ()
        Actual type: [()]

Couldn't match type ‘IO’ with ‘[]’
      Expected type: IO String -> [()]
        Actual type: String -> IO ()
```

I get the impression that there's a much easier way to achieve the desired effect in using `map`. If I executed each statement sequentially then everything works perfectly so perhaps I could use `map` to evaluate `n-1` statements then execute the `nth` one manually?

```
parseProgram :: Parser [HStatement]
parseProgram = spaces *> many (parseEvalHVal <* spaces)

readStatement :: String -> IO [HStatement]
readStatement input = do
         program <- readFile input
         case parse parseProgram "fyp" program of
           Left err -> fail $ show err
           Right parsed -> return $ parsed

evalAndPrint :: Env -> String -> IO ()
evalAndPrint env expr = evalString env expr >>= putStrLn

evalString :: Env -> String -> IO String
evalString env expr = do
         x <- readStatement expr
         putStrLn $ show x
         map (\exprs -> runIOThrows $ liftM show $ evalStatement env exprs) x

run :: String -> IO ()
run expr = nullEnv >>= flip evalAndPrint expr

main :: IO ()
main = do
         args   <- getArgs
         run $ args !! 0

runIOThrows :: IOThrowsError String -> IO String
runIOThrows action = runExceptT (trapError action) >>= return . extractValue
```

Comment: Similar to my comment on the accepted answer, `liftM` is an ancient relic: modern code uses `fmap` or `(<$>)`. Just a matter of style of course, and if you're already deeply accustomed to `liftM` it will do you no harm to stick with it (aside from being applicable less often), but if you can pick one to get used to `fmap` is more fashionable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `mapM` to perform the steps of an `IO` and then retrieve the list of strings:

```
evalString :: Env -> String -> IO [String]
evalString env expr = do
         x <- readStatement expr
         putStrLn (show x)
         mapM (runIOThrows . liftM show . evalStatement env) x
```

This of course gives us a *list* of strings. If you want to post-process that list, for example concatenating the strings, you can `fmap` it:

```
evalString :: Env -> String -> IO String
evalString env expr = do
         x <- readStatement expr
         putStrLn (show x)
         concat <$> mapM (runIOThrows . liftM show . evalStatement env) x
```

Comment: That's perfect! I'm assuming that `mapM` can be used in all instances wherein one needs map when dealing with type `IO a` if that makes any sense?

Comment: @JiangShi FYI `traverse` is a more modern equivalent to `mapM`. If you're going to learn one of them I suggest using `traverse`, since it is more broadly applicable and does the same thing.